# What's the best way to save array in database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

In database I have 2 tables - shops & products.

Simplify..

Products columns:

```
id | name
1  | car
2  | phone
3  | tv
```

Shops columns:

```
id | products
1  | car,tv
2  | phone,tv,cars
3  | tv
```

How to create relation between tables when each shop has many products?
 Is it right to store array of products.id's to each shop?

Comment: You should not store arrays in database. Better solution is add another column in `Products` table called `parent_shop_id` (or similar) to associate products to shop, which results in one-to-many relationship. This is of course assuming you're application stops there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is a many-to-many relationship, you could do something like this:

Product

```
id
name
price
```

Shop

```
id
totalPrice
date
```

ShopItem

```
shop_id
product_id
quantity
```

Comment: "ShopItems" would be the class name at the end there, and "shop_items" the table.

Comment: Also the fields would usually be "shop_id" and "product_id".

Comment: Actually it should have been ShopItem (singular) for the class name (facepalm)